# how can i solve this error "Conversion from string "\N" to type 'Double' is not valid" when loading from a csv file to postgres database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am loading a text file to a postgres database and i am getting this error "Conversion from string "\N" to type 'Double' is not valid." "(CurrentField = GM_Pctg)"

when i open the text file on html, the current field which is "GM_PCTG" starts in a new line.

I am using an ETL Tool to load the text file, Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you tell the import to use CSV format? The literal sequence of characters `\N` is used in place of a NULL when importing text data, but when importing CSV data an unquoted empty string is for NULL, and a quoted empty string like `""` to import a non-NULL string of zero length. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: thanks for the response, I am sorry my source file was a text file and i think that is why it is using \n for null, i am new to postgre, what should i do to solve this problem then?

Comment: See the documentation I linked to. There's an option in the `COPY` command to tell it the format of the input file. You can specify `FORMAT text` or `FORMAT csv`. I don't know what ETL tool you're using, but I suppose it has some user interface to choose the format.

Comment: I am using a bluesky integration studio and my copy command looks like this...copy fact_table(col1,col2....) from <accesskey> wrk_fact_table_bilk.txt credentials<awskey> delimiter '\t' null as '' GZIP

Answer (score 3):

You can tell `COPY` that NULLs are represented as `\N` even in `csv` format:

```
COPY mytab
FROM 'afile'
OPTIONS (FORMAT 'csv', NULL '\N');
```

Comment: I tried this but i am still getting the same error. any ideas?

Comment: copy WRK_fact_m_weekly( vendor ,dpci,dpci_description,store,a_md_dollars ,a_md_pctg ,b_md_dollars,b_md_pctg,c_md_dollars,c_md_pctg,d_md_dollars,d_md_pctg,md_dollars,md_pctg ,vendor_income_dollars,stock_shortage_dollars,employee_discount_dollars,ocos_dollars,net_ship_margin_dollars,gm_dollars,gm_pctg,store_receipts_retail_dollars,store_gross_purchase_cost_dollars) FROM 's3://<CRP>bisS3Bucket</CRP> /WT_Fact_GM_Weekly_Bulk.txt.gz' Credentials'aws_access_key_id=<CRP>bisAWS</CRP>;aws_secret_access_key= <CRP>bisAWSSecretKey</CRP>' Option (FORMAT 'txt', NULL '\N');

Comment: If you want someone to tell you where exactly you went wrong, add the offending line and the `COPY` command *to the question* (as you have noticed, it doesn't work so well in a comment).